# system-config-network-tui for Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Does `system-config-network-tui` or similar exist for Ubuntu?

Or a similar text mode program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no *-tui tools in Debian-based systems. You can [promote](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/25984/) your idea.

Answer (score 2):

As quanta said, these tools don't exist on Ubuntu (at least not on my Ubuntu test machines, and I'm pretty sure they're not available in the apt repositories).

If you can handle `system-config-network-tui` you can probably handle editing the network configuration manually -- [This page has information on the /etc/network/interfaces file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/interfaces.5.html).